# c# store user settings in database

Tags: c#, .net, database, repost

Is there an easy method to store a person's user settings in a sql 2000 database. Ideally all settings in one field so I don't keep having to edit the table every time I add a setting. I am thinking along the lines of serialize a settings class if anyone has an example.

The reason I don't want to use the built in .NET user settings stored in persistent storage is work uses super mandatory profiles so upon a users log off the settings are cleared which is a pain. I posted asking for any solutions to this previously but didn't get much of a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VS designer keeps property settings in the [ApplicationSettingsBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx) class. By default, these properties are serialized/deserialized into a per user XML file. You can override this behavior by using a custom [SettingsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider.aspx) which is where you can add your database functionality. Just add the `SettingsProvider` attribute to the VS generated `Settings` class:

```
[SettingsProvider(typeof(CustomSettingsProvider))]
internal sealed partial class Settings { 
   ...
}
```

A good example of this is the [RegistrySettingsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181001.aspx).

I answered another similar question the same way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170825/how-to-serialize-systemconfigurationsettingsproperty#170932).

Answer (score 1):

you can easily serialize classes in C#: http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+serializer.  You can either store the XML in a varchar field, or if you want to use the binary serializer, you can store it in an "Image" datatype, which is really just binary.

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize into a database, or you could create a User settings table containing Name-Value pairs and keyed by UserId. The advantage of doing it this way is it's easier to query and update through RDMS tools.

Answer (score 0):

First you need your table.

```
create table user_settings
(
  user_id nvarchar(256) not null,
  keyword nvarchar(64) not null,
    constraint PK_user_settings primary key (user_id, keyword),
  value nvarchar(max) not null
)
```

Then you can build your API:

```
public string GetUserSetting(string keyword, string defaultValue);
public void SetUserSetting(string keyword, string value);
```

If you're already doing CRUD development (which I assume from the existence and availability of a database), then this should be trivially easy to implement.