# How can I store values in a variable permanently even after restarting machine?

Tags: c#

I want to store values permanently in a variable. The same variable should be able to be edited and saved by user, and whatever it is I need the value of the variable from the last time I modified it, like a database. Please explain me with some examples!

Comment: depending on whether you application is multi user etc then the simplest solution would be to use the built in Settings in .net  your question doesnt really give enough information but you could check here for a start... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: A bit more information would be useful, what kind of application are you building? Windows? Web?

Comment: Um, write it to a file. Your question does not should that least bit of evidence that you have done research first, or tried to solve it on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to serialize it somewhere that persists when the computer is rebooted, and then read it when your program starts again.  This could be a database, (for simpler DBs, look at something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)) an XML file, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You need persistent storage for this (database, file, registry, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your application you can save your variables for example in a config file or database.

After your application gets started again you load the settings.

- [MSDN - Application Settings Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx)
- [c# store user settings in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171352/c-sharp-store-user-settings-in-database)

Answer (score 2):

write the data in a file. when you than restart the application you can read the parameters out of this file and set some variables.

file could mean - sql, db, ini or whatever you are using.

all the best

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Properties.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) advantage is that you can Save a variable per user scope or have Application scope at the same time

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Properties.Settings1.Default.Test = "StackOverFlow";
            Properties.Settings1.Default.Save();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```